# Ominauth: Google_oauth2 error in rails devise email confirmation issues (You have to confirm your email address before continuing.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, google-oauth, omniauth

I'm trying use the google login oauth2 in my project, all the codes successfully fixed in right position but I dont want the google oauth2 features to request for email verification just straight to login, I prefer it to get skipped, how do I achieve this without removing the :confirmable devise module? this is my code user.rb in model

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:github, :google_oauth2]

         has_many :friends 

        

         
        
         def self.from_omniauth(access_token)
    data = access_token.info
    user = User.where(email: data['email']).first
    unless user
         user = User.create(
            email: data['email'],
            password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
         )
     
     end
     user
end
end
```

> This is code for the omniauth callback controller .rb

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

def google_oauth2

  handle_auth "Google"
  
  end

  def github

    handle_auth "Github"
      
  end

  def handle_auth(kind)
      # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
      @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

      if @user.persisted?
        flash[:notice] = I18n.t 'devise.omniauth_callbacks.success', kind: kind
        sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
      else
        session['devise.auth_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].except('extra') # Removing extra as it can overflow some session stores
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url, alert: @user.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
      end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The Devise Confirmable Module provides a [skip_confirmation!](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable#skip_confirmation!-instance_method) method to do this. In your `from_omniauth` function, instead of

```
user = User.create(
    email: data['email'],
    password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
)
```

Instead do this

```
user = User.new(
    email: data['email'],
    password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
)
user.skip_confirmation!
user.save!
```